# Firestore getDocs last item get updated

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

While I'm trying to get all stored user info and update all items data, but the problem is that only last item from the array getting updated, how can I fix this?

```
// Tasks.js

const Tasks = ({
  navigation,
  path,
  currentLevelName,
  route,
  currLevelParam,
}) => {
  const [levels, setLevels] = useState([]);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

  const {
    steps,
    setSteps,
    step,
    setStep,
    taskIndex,
    setTaskIndex,
    levelName,
    setLevelName,
  } = useContext(DataContext);

  const { promptAsync, request, user, error, logout, uid } = useAuth();
  const colRef = collection(db, path);

  useEffect(() => {
    setisLoading(true);
    const getLevels = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(colRef);
      setLevels(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      setisLoading(false);
    };
    getLevels();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTaskIndex = levels.map((item, index) => {
      return settiList(index);
    });
  }, [levels]);


  // Get userInfo
  const userRef = collection(db, `user/${uid}/${currentLevelName}`);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserInfo = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(userRef);
      data &&
        setUserData(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    getUserInfo();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userInfo =
      userData &&
      userData.map((items) => {
        setStep(items.step);
        setSteps(items.steps);
        setTaskIndex(items.taskIndex);
        setLevelName(items.levelName);
      });
  }, [userData]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
     
        levels.map((item, index) => (
    
            <View key={index}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  navigation.navigate('Stages', {
                    id: item.id,
                    currentLevelName,
                    index,
                  })
                }
                >
                <View>
                  <Text
                    {item.kuName}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Task
                step={
                index === taskIndex && currentLevelName == 
                levelName && step
                }
                steps={
                index === taskIndex && currentLevelName == 
                levelName && steps
                }
                height={10}
                data={item}
                hideCloseIcon={() => sethideCloseIcon(true)}
              />
            </View>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};



//Stages.js

const Stages = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const id = route?.params?.id;
  const currLevelParam = route?.params?.currentLevelName;
  const index = route?.params?.index;

  const [stages, setStages] = useState(db);
  const [currentStageIndex, setCurrentStageIndex] = useState(0);
  const [filteredStages, setFilteredStages] = useState([]);
  const [receivedItems, setReceivedItems] = useState([]);
  const [newItems, setNewItems] = useState([]);
  const [isCorrect, setIsCorrect] = useState(false);
  const [isInCorrect, setIsInCorrect] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(false);

  const {
    steps,
    setSteps,
    step,
    setStep,
    taskIndex,
    setTaskIndex,
    levelName,
    setLevelName,
  } = useContext(DataContext);

  const { promptAsync, request, user, error, logout, uid } = useAuth();

  const colRef = collection(
    db,
    `enKurd/${currLevelParam}/tasks/${id}/bySentence/`
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setLevelName(currLevelParam);
  }, [currLevelParam]);

  //Get data
  useEffect(() => {
    setisLoading(true);
    const getStages = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(colRef);
      setStages(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      setisLoading(false);
    };
    getStages();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filteredStage =
      stages &&
      Object.entries(stages)[currentStageIndex].map((stage) => {
        return stage;
      });
    setFilteredStages(filteredStage);
  }, [stages && stages, currentStageIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTaskIndex(index);
  }, index);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLevelName(currLevelParam);
  }, [currLevelParam]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setNewItems([]);
    setReceivedItems([]);
    setStep(0);
    setIsCorrect(false);
    setCurrentStageIndex(0);
  }, [stages, index]);


  //Get selected value
  const handleSelected = (e) => {
    setReceivedItems(e);
  };

  //Get next stage
  const handleNext = () => {
    if (step === steps) {
      navigation.navigate('CompletedTasks', { index, currLevelParam });
    } else {
      setCurrentStageIndex((prevStat) => prevStat + 1);
      setFilteredStages((currTask) => [...currTask, filteredStages]);
      setIsCorrect(false);
      setIsInCorrect(false);
      setNewItems([]);
    }
  };

  // Get stages length
  useEffect(() => {
    setSteps(_.size(stages));
  }, [stages, currentStageIndex]);

  //Update selected data at first render
  useEffect(() => {
    setNewItems((prevState) => [...prevState, receivedItems]);
  }, [receivedItems]);

  const deleteWord = (receivedItem) => {...};

  function arrComp(...args) {...}

  // Check if correct
  useEffect(() => {...}, [!isCorrect ? newItems : !newItems]);


  //Set userInfo
  useEffect(() => {
    const setUser = async () => {
      await setDoc(doc(db, `user/${uid}/${levelName}/${taskIndex}/`), {
        uid: uid,
        step: step,
        steps: steps,
        taskIndex: taskIndex,
        levelName: levelName,
      });
    };

    return setUser;
  }, [step]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{...}}
    >
      <Header
        stp={step}
        stps={steps}
        goBack={() => navigation.navigate('Home', { index, currLevelParam })}
      />

      <View style={{...}}>
        <View
          style={{...}}
        >
          {newItems &&
            newItems.map((receivedItem, i) => (
              <TouchableOpacity...>
                {receivedItem.length < 1 ? (
                  ''
                ) : (
                  <Button .../>
                )}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
        </View>

        {isLoading
          ? filteredStages.map((items, i) => (
              <View ...>
                {items?.enWords?.map((i) => (
                  <View key={i}>
                   {...}
                  </View>
                ))}
              </View>
            ))
          : filteredStages &&
            filteredStages.map((items, i) => (
              <View key={i}>
                {items &&
                  items?.enWordsR?.map((enWordsR, i) => (...)}
              </View>
            ))}

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Button
            ...
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

each level has their special array indexes and each level get only one item, which is last one, but I get all items from Firestore,
As I said each level has multiple tasks for example level 1 has 2 tasks and each task has their own stages in this case will have 2 steps which is the length of task 1 if user pass stage 1 will update firestore for that and step will increase by +1, and same for other tasks, but as I said the problem is here when user kill the app and come back he only see last task get updated on whatever stages he passed before, so I want to update all task step and steeps status at once

[image: Firebase schema]

This is what i get from firestore:

```
 [ Object {
    "id": "0",
    "levelName": "level2",
    "step": 1,
    "steps": 1,
    "taskIndex": 0,
    "uid": "0kAf19qUoEgJgYCAlS1GRkx0LEZ2",
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "id": "0",
    "levelName": "level1",
    "step": 1,
    "steps": 2,
    "taskIndex": 0,
    "uid": "0kAf19qUoEgJgYCAlS1GRkx0LEZ2",
  },
  Object {
    "id": "1",
    "levelName": "level1",
    "step": 1,
    "steps": 1,
    "taskIndex": 1,
    "uid": "0kAf19qUoEgJgYCAlS1GRkx0LEZ2",
  },
]
}],
```

Comment: Can you share your complete component so it'll be clear how you are trying to render the data? A table or so?

Comment: I'm not rendering the firestore data but updating some info such as steps and step, check userInfo function on useEffect this is where user details get updated, to make it more clear for you, let's assume you have passed two stages from each level of game, and you store these passed stage on firestore, and if you try to update these passed stage for user and you got only second stage of level updated

Comment: I'm carious why some questions get more than 11k answers, and we don't get only one?

Comment: When you say "update all data", do you mean updating the UI or Firestore documents somehow? It's still not clear where you are trying to show the data. You are updating the state after every iteration on `userData` so that state will only have the last element as previous one will be overwritten. It might be best to share the result that you are expecting.

Comment: As i said each level has multiple tasks for example level 1 has 2 tasks and each task has their own stages in this case will have 2 steps which is the length of task 1 if user pass stage 1  will update firestore for that and step will increase by +1, and same for other tasks, but as I said the problem is here when user kill the app and come back he only see last task get updated on whatever stages he passed before, so I want to update all task step and steeps status at once

Comment: Updated the code, check it please

Comment: So all I want now is that, i want to show all stages step numbers when get updated, right now it's overwriting previews step but i want to keep previews and current one

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by my self somehow, not sure if it's correct way.

Changed adding data to firestore  to this

```
  doc(db, `user/${uid}/${levelName}/${uid}/${taskIndex}/data`),
```

And update UI like this:

```
  db,`user/${uid}/${currentLevelName}/${uid}/${tiList}`);
```

and then fire all tiList (which is task index state) on `GetUserData` useEffect, and also adding `level` dependency on tiList useEffect